# Hyperledger fabric peers throwing vscc error and not committing new blocks

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js, hyperledger-fabric2.2, hyperledger-fabric-peer

My hyperledger fabric peers are throwing the following vscc error:

```
2021-08-30 08:25:41.694 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 242 Received block [84] from buffer channel=assetschannel
2021-08-30 08:25:41.727 UTC [vscc] Validate -> ERRO 243 VSCC error: stateBasedValidator.Validate failed, err unexpected EOF
2021-08-30 08:25:41.728 UTC [committer.txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 244 Dispatch for transaction txId = 463b57826a54e16921aa153617a824e39514550c25a7c5816fb77bde3386f357 returned error: unexpected EOF
2021-08-30 08:25:41.728 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> ERRO 245 Validation failed: unexpected EOF channel=assetschannel
2021-08-30 08:25:41.728 UTC [gossip.state] commitBlock -> ERRO 246 Got error while committing(unexpected EOF
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).commitBlock
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:799
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:571
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374)
2021-08-30 08:25:41.728 UTC [gossip.state] deliverPayloads -> ERRO 247 Failed executing VSCC due to unexpected EOF. Aborting chain processing
```

This happened right after adding key-level endorsement policy in the chaincode. After executing the transaction, the fabric-sdk stopped receiving the commit event and peers stopped receiving new blocks from the ordering nodes. Prior to adding key-level endorsement policy and execution of transaction, the peers were committing new blocks and there was no issue. Now, even the chaincode upgrade transaction is not being committed.

Peer ledger height:
Blockchain info: `{"height":84,"currentBlockHash":"K2uPQ6E8BqvCDi1BsIpc5pnRPUGwpeM3ejlFLgiLuOM=","previousBlockHash":"BtlZSJ9Q0tpou4NhVtckRr26BM0pMPe5Z3J5qOto6PM="}`

Orderer log shows that the latest block is 101

```
021-08-30 07:56:43.587 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] writeBlock -> INFO 047 Writing block [98] (Raft index: 130) to ledger channel=assetschannel node=2
2021-08-30 07:57:25.418 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] writeBlock -> INFO 048 Writing block [99] (Raft index: 131) to ledger channel=assetschannel node=2
2021-08-30 08:05:09.380 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] writeBlock -> INFO 049 Writing block [100] (Raft index: 132) to ledger channel=assetschannel node=2
2021-08-30 08:08:34.060 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] writeBlock -> INFO 04a Writing block [101] (Raft index: 133) to ledger channel=assetschannel node=2
```

Any suggestions/feedback would be helpful

Comment: are you using couchDB? Can you upload the contents of the block?

Comment: yes I am using couchdb. I have shared the content of the block to you